# Persist all cookies in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I'm looking to persist all cookies in localStorage. When the page is loaded the cookies should be inflated from the data in localStorage. Whenever they change, or possibly just on page close, localStorage should be updated with the cookie data.

I'm in an environment where cookies do not persist between restarts and you're expected to use localStorage. The problem is that the server framework I'm using sets all the cookies independently of my code.

Thanks for any help navigating this -- I don't know my way around cookie behavior that well.

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage API operates on a simple set/get/clear set of methods that allow you to interact with a key-value store. To store all the cookies for the current page under the key "cookies" you could write:

```
localStorage.setItem("cookies", document.cookie);
```

and later recover them by:

```
document.cookie = localStorage.getItem("cookies");
```